# Databinding not working correctly

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7.1

I think this may be a bug. I have a page with a pivot control with 5 items:

Each PivotItem reference the same Template as a static resource and they each have a different datacontext (an ObservableCollection). The template has a ListBox and a TextBlock. Both use a value converter for visibility. Basically it hides and shows them accordingly based on whether the Collection is empty or not:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="PhoneApp2.PivotPage1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:PhoneApp2"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <p:CollectionToVisibilityConverter x:Key="CollectionToVisibility" />
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Template">
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CollectionToVisibility}, ConverterParameter=false}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1}" Padding="5,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text2}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Empty" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CollectionToVisibility}, ConverterParameter=true}" />
        </StackPanel>

    </ControlTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="150" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item1" DataContext="{Binding Model1}" Template="{StaticResource Template}" />
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item2" DataContext="{Binding Model2}" Template="{StaticResource Template}" />
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item3" DataContext="{Binding Model3}" Template="{StaticResource Template}" />
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item4" DataContext="{Binding Model4}" Template="{StaticResource Template}" />
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item5" DataContext="{Binding Model5}" Template="{StaticResource Template}" />
    </controls:Pivot>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Content="Clear Items" Click="Button_Click" />
        <Button Content="Add Items" Click="Button_Click_1" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class PivotPage1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public PivotPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm = new ViewModel();

        vm.Model1 = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        vm.Model2 = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        vm.Model3 = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        vm.Model4 = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        vm.Model5 = new ObservableCollection<Model>();

        Populate(vm);

        DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void Populate(ViewModel vm)
    {
        vm.Model1.Add(new Model { Text1 = "1", Text2 = "World" });
        vm.Model1.Add(new Model { Text1 = "1", Text2 = "Planet" });

        vm.Model2.Add(new Model { Text1 = "2", Text2 = "World" });
        vm.Model2.Add(new Model { Text1 = "2", Text2 = "Planet" });

        vm.Model3.Add(new Model { Text1 = "3", Text2 = "World" });
        vm.Model3.Add(new Model { Text1 = "3", Text2 = "Planet" });

        vm.Model4.Add(new Model { Text1 = "4", Text2 = "World" });
        vm.Model4.Add(new Model { Text1 = "4", Text2 = "Planet" });

        vm.Model5.Add(new Model { Text1 = "5", Text2 = "World" });
        vm.Model5.Add(new Model { Text1 = "5", Text2 = "Planet" });
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel vm = DataContext as ViewModel;
        vm.Model1.Clear();
        vm.Model2.Clear();
        vm.Model3.Clear();
        vm.Model4.Clear();
        vm.Model5.Clear();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel vm = DataContext as ViewModel;
        Populate(vm);
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Model1 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Model2 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Model3 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Model4 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Model5 { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
}
```

Converter:

```
public class CollectionToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        IList list = value as IList;
        bool isEmptyVisible = false;
        if (parameter != null)
            bool.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out isEmptyVisible);

        if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
            return isEmptyVisible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

        return isEmptyVisible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If you run this app and clear and repopulate the collections (pressing the buttons) you will notice that some pivot items work as expected, and other don't.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: How about you bother telling *how* they doesn't work as expected, rather than expecting people to run your code. There's nothing wrong in the above code, so the problem is obviously elsewhere.

Comment: @Claus from the question above: "If you run this app and clear and repopulate the collections (pressing the buttons) you will notice that some pivot items work as expected, and other don't". To be more specific, some pivot items rebind themselves as expected, while the others stay the same. The code was added so it can be ran locally and other could replicate the problem.

Comment: @JonasStawski which items are updated and which are not? Do you have a full repro?

Comment: @MattLacey I think the current pivot item, the one before, and the one after are updated, while the others are not. The code posted here is a single page app that will replicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that sticks out is the absence of INotifyPropertyChanged on your Model class

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string m_Text1;
    public string Text1 
    { 
        get { return m_Text1;} 
        set { m_Text1 = value; 
              OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text1")); }

    // ...

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged: Shared bit
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Comment: The bound property, Model1, Model2, etc are the ones changing. Those are ObservableCollection which has the property changed mechanism built in.